# Identifying failures in Jenkins Console Output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We run CI tests via Jenkins and review the results via Jenkin's Console Output. If one of the tests doesn't pass, it is printed to the Console in red. Nevertheless, the output is very long and it is tedious to search the entire log to find instances of red output. Are there any good solutions to the issue?

For instance, Gerrit's user interface displays file diffs and a user can use keyboard shortcuts <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>p</kbd> to jump to the next/previous diff block. Is there any such solution/plugin... for Jenkins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [Collapsing Console Sections Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Collapsing+Console+Sections+Plugin):

> This plugin allows the creation of sections in build consoles.These sections can be individually collapsed to hide unimportant details. A floating outline widget is available to navigate through all the sections of a build.

and the [Console Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Console+Parser+Plugin):

> The console parser plugin parses the console log generated by the Jenkins build allowing for:
>
> - ...
> - highlighting of errors, warnings , and info
> - ...
> - separating the comparison log by sections
> - collapsible sections for faster viewing

Answer (score 1):

You should use a *reporting plugin* in Jenkins corresponding to the test framework you have used in your project. e.g. If you are using TestNG , then Jenkins has a **publish TestNG reports** plugin for filtering out test results. 
Similarly for **Cucumber** - there is **pretty cucumber reports** plugin.

Comment: Good idea. Specifically, I'd still like to be able to take advantage of the log output. A reporting plugin will help for summaries, but I'm also looking for something that will ease my navigation of the raw output...